# Where can I obtain the Google Base feeds for Real Estate?

Tags: rss, google-base

Does Google provide a feed so that I can read IN their Google Base Real Estate database?

http://base.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=66779&hl=en

If so, where is this feed and how do I access it?

**UPDATE**:

To clarify more ... everything I've seen on Google Base documentation for Real Estate talks about ways for someone to **submit** a feed. What I'm looking for is to see if Google **provides** those feeds so that others can consume them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Query process](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/base/docs/2.0/attrs-queries.html) is pretty straightforward:

> When you search for Google Base data,
>   your query goes against a data item
>   feed. There are two data item feeds:
>   the public snippets feed and the
>   customer-specific items feed.
>
> ```
> * http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets:
> ```
>
> The snippets feed contains all Google
>   Base data and is available to anyone
>   to query against without a need for
>   authentication. This feed is
>   read-only. The snippets feed provides
>   access to all content in Google Base,
>   but may return items with a shortened
>   description, and missing private attributes.
>
> ```
> * http://www.google.com/base/feeds/items:
> ```
>
> The items feed contains a
>   customer-specific subset of Google
>   Base data. Only the customer can
>   access this feed to insert, update,
>   delete and query his own data. The
>   items feed requires authentication.

For example you could query for Housing in NY with a query like [this](http://www.google.com/base/feeds/snippets/-/housing?bq=%5Blocation%3A%40%22100%20Wall%20St%2C%20New%20York%2C%20NY%2C%20USA%22%20%2B%203mi%5D).

Comment: @systempuntoout, Thanks !!!  One more question, any idea on how I can take the link you have above to *only* output the following data: address, city, state, zip, # of bedrooms, # of bathrooms, price and sqft?  The link above seems to provide extra information I'm not interested in.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this comment?